# Нужна ли запятая после слов "по технологии"?

Tags: пунктуация

"По технологии для  приготовления смузи используется не только жидкая составляющая плода, но и его мякоть".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используется (на каком основании? почему?)по технологии - обстоятельство, следовательно, не вводное и не обособляется. Однако запятая возможна как авторская при использовании слова в значении "как диктует(говорит) технология".

Answer (score 1):

**По технологии для приготовления смузи используется не только жИдкая составляющая плода, но и его мЯкоть.**

В этом предложении даже авторское обособление обстоятельства затруднительно, так как интонация используется для выражения  однородных отношений со значением сопоставления.

Кроме того, это технический текст, а обстоятельство недостаточно распространенное.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы запятую поставил, дабы избежать двусмысленности (То ли "по технологии", то ли "по технологии для приготовления смузи")

Comment: А здесь  обстоятельством надо считать "по технологии",  так как существует "технология приготовления", а не "технология для приготовления".